# Big-O of These Nested Loops

Tags: java, performance, loops, big-o, time-complexity

I'm pretty new to the Big-O field, so bear with me here. I have been searching about it as much as I could but I still need a lot of work to fully understand it.
I came across these nested for loops in a practicing exercises and there wasn't any solutions and they seem complicated. So, any help would be appreciated.

### 1)

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i < n^2; i++) { // n+1
    for(int j = n-1; j >= n-1-i; j–-) { // n(n+1)/2 ?
        sum = i+j; // n(n+1)/2 ?
        System.out.println(sum); // n(n+1)/2 ?
    }
}
```

Big-O = ?

### 2)

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=1; i <= 2^n; i=i*2) { // log(n)
    for(int j=0; j <= log(i); j++) { // log(n(n+1)/2) ?
        sum = i+j; // log(n(n+1)/2) ?
        System.out.println(sum); // log(n(n+1)/2) ?
    }
}
```

Big-O = ?

### 3)

```
int sum = 0; int k = 23;
for(int i=k; i <= 2^(n−k); i=i*2) { // log(n)
    for(int j=2^(i−k); j < 2^(i+k); j=j*2) { // log(log(n)) ?
        sum = i+j; // log(log(n)) ?
        System.out.println(sum); // log(log(n)) ?
    }
}
```

Big-O = ?

### 4)

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=2n; i>=1; i=i/2) {
    for(int j=i; j>=1; j=j/2) {
        sum = i+j;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Big-O = ?

---

**EDIT:**
- Corrected #4. Sorry for the mess up.
- Base of the log is 2.
- The **^** here means "to the power", not xor.

Comment: Which base is the log you're using? I'll use base 2 for simplicity in my answer.

Comment: The fourth is a redundancy of the second.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty questions like ["Big-O of nested loops" here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Big-O%20of%20nested%20loops) (and answers).

However, you will get an answer from me. But first there is a notation problem:
You tagged this question as java. In the code I see something like `2ⁿ` or `n²`. In [java this means `xor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510701/big-o-for-3-nested-loops?rq=1), but I think you meant `Math.pow(2,n)` instead, so for this answer I will treat it as a power operator.

1. ```
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=0; i < n^2; i++) {             // outer loop
       for(int j = n-1; j >= n-1-i; j–-) {  // inner loop
           sum = i+j;                       // inner operations
           System.out.println(sum);
       }
   }
   ```

   The inner operations runs in `O(1)`, so I just counting how often they are called.

   - The outer loop runs `n²` times.
   - for each `i` (from the outer loop) the inner loop runs `i` times.

   In total you get `0+1+...+(n²-1)+n² = n²(n²+1)/2`. This is in `Θ(n⁴)`.
2. ```
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=1; i <= 2^n; i=i*2) {           // outer loop
       for(int j=0; j <= log(i); j++) {      // inner loop
           sum = i+j;                        // inner operations
           System.out.println(sum); 
       }
   }
   ```

   - The outer loop runs `n` times, since `2⋅2⋅2⋅...⋅2` (`n` times) equals 2<sup>n</sup>.
   - The inner loop runs `k` times for each i=2<sup>k</sup> (1 ≤ k ≤ n), assuming the base of the logarithm is 2.

   In total you get `1+2+3+...+n-1+n = n(n+1)/2`. This is in `Θ(n²)`.
3. ```
   int sum = 0; int k = 23;
   for(int i=k; i <= 2^(n−k); i=i*2) {          // outer loop
       for(int j=2^(i−k); j < 2^(i+k); j=j*2) { // inner loop
           sum = i+j;                           // inner operations 
           System.out.println(sum);             
       }
   }
   ```

   - The outer loop runs `m` times with `m` minimal such that `k⋅2m > 2n-k` holds. This can be written as `k⋅2k⋅2m > 2n`. `k` has to be positiv (otherwise the outer loop will run forever). Assuming `k` is  bounded by `O(n)` (canstants are also in `O(n)`), `m` is also bounded by `O(n)`.
   - The inner loop runs always `2⋅k` times, no matter what `i` or `n` is. This is in `O(1)` for a constant `k` and in `O(n)` for a `k` bounded by `O(n)`.

   In total you get `O(n)` for a constant `k` and `O(n²)` for a `k` in `O(n)`.
4. ```
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=2n; i>=1; i=i/2) {       // outer loop
       for(int j=i; j>=1; j=j/2) {    // inner loop
           sum = i+j;                 // inner operations
           System.out.println(sum);
       }
   }
   ```

   - The outer loop runs `log(n)` times just like in case 2 (the other way around)
   - The inner loop runs `j` times for (basicly) each power of 2 between `1` and `2n`.

   Assuming `n = 2k` (means `log(n) = k`) you get in total
   `2k+1+2k+2k-1+...+22+21+20=2k+2-1=4n-1`. So this in in `O(n)`. This also holds for n not a power of 2.

Comment: @iMe I added an answer for #4

Answer (score 1):

Methodically finding a solution for your iterative algorithms using Sigma notation:

[image]

---

Using base 2 for the log below:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Just corrected #4. Could please you explain in words what are you doing in each step?