# Determining the time & space complexity for nested loop with one constant factor

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

```
for 1 to n
 for j=1 to 3
    for i=j to n
       count++
```

**My answer: O(n^2)**

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank You

edit: The Innermost loop runs for O(n) as well as the Outermost loop. But what about j=1 to 3 ?

edit 2: From what I have learned, Space complexity can be calculated if there are -

- Variable Declaration
- Data Structures
- Allocations
- Function Call

But there are none of those in the above code. So what will be the space complexity ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O for 3 nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510701/big-o-for-3-nested-loops)

Comment: You're correct as the 2nd line is a constant factor and doesn't affect the big-O complexity

Comment: thank you @silleknarf for the answer.

Comment: Yes. You're right. The complexity is accurately (3*n*(n+1))/2 and in complexity world it's O(n^2).

Comment: @AliJP It's actually `n(3n-2)` because the `j` in the third loop comes from the second loop, not the first one.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to s-o! It's not clear exactly what your question is: is it how to calculate complexity? Do you have specific question about the computation in this example? Just giving your answer (without working) and asking if it's correct doesn't make a good question because it's not clear what your specific problem is (other than presumably to hand in correct homework).

Comment: @PaulHankin yes. As i have said in the edited section, I don't know how to calculate the 2nd loop.

Comment: I have added my thoughts on the space complexity. Can anyone help me there as well ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's O(n^2) because:

- for 1 is O(n)
- for 2 is O(1) - Final number of actions
- for 3 is O(n) - i->n is still O(n) because the order depends on n

**sum up - O(n^2).**

Comment: I have added my thoughts on the space complexity. Can you help me there as well ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is to rewrite the code as follows:

```
for x= 1 to n
    for i = 1 to n
        count++
    for i = 2 to n
        count++
    for i = 3 to n    // considering 1 to 3 => [1, 3]
        count++
```

Then, we can argue that the time Complexity of all inner loops are `O(n)`, i.e., `O(n) + O(n) + O(n)` = `O(n)`.

The Time complexity of outer loop is also `O(n)` and for every iteration of outer loop we have `O(n)` iterations in the inner loop making it `O(n^2)`.

Also, Space Complexity is `O(1)` as there are only a few variable declarations (the variables declared are: `count`, `i`, `j`; also you forgot to declare a variable in the outermost loop) that don't depend on any external parameter, i.e., the Space Complexity remains the same irrespective of the size of input.