# Big O complexity of inner loops

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

The Big O of Outer loop is O(n),and I think second inner loop big O is log(n) but I cant't figure the big O of the third inner loop

```
for(i=0;i<n;i+=2)
{
    for(j=1;j<i*i;j*=3)
    {
       for(k=2;k*k<=n;k++){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O for 3 nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510701/big-o-for-3-nested-loops)

Comment: `(j=1;j<i*i;i*=3)` – I'm assuming this is a typo or interview-style trick question? Otherwise this loop would never terminate as `j` never increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outermost loop gets executed n-2 times making the complexity O(n).
In the second loop the value of j increases in powers of 3 up to i*i that is equal to log3(i*i). so for both the loops combined, it is ∑ <sub>i=1</sub><sup>n-2</sup>   log3(i) which is equal to log3(n!) or simply  n*log(n) as you mentioned. The innermost loop gets executed sqrt(n) times making the total complexity O(n*log(n)*sqrt(n))

Comment: Adding an explanation for why you believe that what you're saying is indeed the case would improve this answer quite a lot.